# Get users list from identity server

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, identityserver4

I am implementing Identity Server admin where admin can see all the users and also add/update or delete users.

What is the best way to implement it?

I got a link https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2607 which suggest that I should create a separate secured API which will talk to same database of identity server.

Is that correct way. Kindly recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is stated that you should create an **application** for management of Users, Resources, etc.

Scott Brady states [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38302121/894705) that you can write your own API or use another package like `IdentityManager`.

However, IdentityManager package is no longer active, you can use [`IdentityServer4.Admin`](https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin) package instead.